# Adding the event section to ionCalendar using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to add the event section in the first place?  Here is my code.

```
<script>
      $("#calendar").ionCalendar({
    lang: "en",                     // language
    sundayFirst: false,             // first week day
    years: "80",                    // years diapason
    format: "DD.MM.YYYY",           // date format
    onClick: function(date){        // click on day returns date
        console.log(date);
      }
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked out the [documentation](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.calendar/en.html) lovingly prepared and published by the author to help make use of his hard work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used like this..

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#calendar").ionCalendar({
lang:"en", // set the language of the calendar. Each additional language requires its own localization file
years:"1915-1995", // Specifies the years range
sundayFirst: false,
onClick:function(date){ // Callback function. 
$("#calendar-text").html("onClick:<br/>"+date);
}
});
</script>
```